# How to get the hidden nodes of a webpage with Xpath?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am trying to get some elements with python selenium.

When I inspect, I make a right-click on the element of the page and it shows the code in the dom.
So I successfully identify the correct XPath.

But then, when I execute my python selenium script, it doesn't detect the nodes.

So I had a second look at the dom and I can see the nodes are hidden. They only show when I made an inspection on it.

Please look at this screenshot:
[image]

You can see in grey all the hidden elements.

Does anyone already face this scenario? How can I get these elements when they are hidden? is there a hack?

Answer (score 1):

The "hidden" elements are script blocks. So you can't click on them as they are not part of the UI of the page, they are part of the logic. A script is just not clickable, it has no size, no color and no position.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer will not be accepted since this user normally not accepting answers, only asking.. I gave you an upvote thou for the good explanations :)

Comment: @Prophet Thanks. It is polite to accept answers

Comment: You are welcome טל :) This also the recommendation of SO but some people just don't care...